# Recursive function in C (to print a piramid of #)

Tags: c, cs50

I´m following the famous course cs50.

During a class, the teacher showed a program that printed out a pyramid of a height given as an input from the user:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void pyramid(int n);

int main (void)
{
    int height = get_int("height:");
    pyramid(height);
    return 0;
}

void pyramid(int n)
{
    if (n==0)
    {
        return;
    }
    pyramid(n-1);

    for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Can please someone explain me, what the recursive function pyramid does?
I debug it and I see that given the input is checking if it is equalto 0, then it calls itself until n==0 and returns. After that the debugger goes to the loop for and does it n time.

Following a liner path, it is not supposed to go to the for loop. 
Why it does it?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The function call `piramid (n-1);` is really just like any other function calls, once it returns the execution continues with the statements that follows it. In this case the `for` loop. So when you have `n == 1` then you call `piramid(0)` which return immediately, and you do the loop in the `piramid(1)` call. Then it returns and you do the loop in the `piramid(2)` call. And so on.

Comment: You should do some research on how recursive calls terminate.  n=0 is the base case.  Once this returns all of the previous calls continue running one at a time.  Thus, only after n=0 do the n=1 to n=infinity cases start to enter the for loop.  This operation ensures the the top of the pyramid is drawn first.

Answer (score 3):

After some value of `height` is set, then a function `piramid` is called. If the value of `height` is `0`, then the function finishes. Otherwise it calls itself with decreased argument `height`, which allows you to print each level of the pyramide. As you can see in the body of `void piramid(int n)`, it calls itself first, then prints `n` "blocks".

Let's say we are working with `height = n` and try to analyze what happens (each dot is another step):

- `piramid(n)` calls:
- `piramid(n-1)` calls:
- `piramid(n-2)` calls:
- ...
- `piramid(1)` calls:
- `piramid(0)` - that returns nothing, it is the last recursive call of `piramid`, so we start going back: in our case it means we print hashes in the order from top to bottom:
- `#` is printed, as `piramid(1)` is on top of the stack and after we print it, then we pop it, so `piramid(2)` becomes the first element on top
- `##` are printed, `piramid(2)` is on top of the stack, we pop it and continue working with other calls the same way,
- ...
- (n-1) `#` are printed, we pop it from the stack,
- n `#` are printed, our stack is now empty.

Answer (score 2):

To make it understandable, let's take an example with a small number :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void piramid (int n);

int
main (void)
{
  piramid (2);
}

void
piramid (int n)
{
  if (n == 0)
    {
      return;
    }
  piramid (n - 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      printf ("#");
    }
  printf ("\n");
}
```

What it does:

- main calls piramid(2)
- piramid(2) calls piramid(1) however piramid(2) didn't finish as you stated
- piramid(1) calls piramid(0)
- piramid(0) does nothing as it returns immediately
- piramid(1) finishes and prints #
- piramid(2) finishes and prints ##

If n was bigger it would follow this but with more steps

Hope it could help and sorry if my answer isn't great as it's my first try answering on stackoverflow (if you have suggestions of how I should answer don't hesitate to tell me)

Comment: Great answer! Very clear to understand and explains the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion arises from not being aware of the execution context and the callstack. One should know the Memory model of the programming language in question, which is crucial to understand how function calls work.

The recursive calls are added to the
callstack in the order when they are
called,with the first recursive call being
at the bottom of the stack and the most
recent recursive call at the top of the
stack. The recursive calls remember
where they left their execution(execution context) and call themselves with (n-1) as the argument until n<=0, in which case, the stack gets recoiled, with the latest recursive call resumes its execution from where it left off in the first place, and the
subsequent calls in the stack get executed
sequentially with the very first recursive
call gets executed the last. All the function calls are getting executed in a single thread of execution.